# amalgamate two ruby arrays

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Very simple one, but I need to run a bit of code for each admin user in a system plus 1 other user.

I can get the admin users like this.

```
account.users.where(:hr => 1).map(&:id)
```

and the individual user like this

```
user.manager_id
```

so how do I put these together to produce one unique array, as the user identified in the second piece of code "may" be found in the second. The code below seems to work, but I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing it

```
myarray = []
a.employees.where(:hr => 1).each do |user|
  myarray << user.id
end

myarray << user.line_manager_id
myarray.uniq
```

This seems wrong as I am creating lots of objects just to get their IDs?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the array "union" method [Array#|](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-7C):

```
account.users.where(:hr => 1).map(&:id) | [user.manager_id]
```

Comment: Excellent answer although an explanation would be really nice. Especially since the union(`|`) operator is not one people utilize often.

Comment: Thanks, @engineersmnky. The link to the method was in-progress... :-)

Comment: Instead of `map(&:id)` use [`ids`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-ids)

Comment: @Stefan, that's probably related to Rails, which is foreign to me, but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: It is. `ids` fetches the id attributes without instantiating any records. (*"This seems wrong as I am creating lots of objects just to get their IDs?"*)

Answer (score 1):

```
myarray = a.employees.where(:hr => 1).pluck(:id)
myarray << user.line_manager_id

myarray.uniq!
```

Documentation:

[uniq!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21)

[pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

Comment: `uniq!` seems like a bad choice in the event that the array is already unique. e.g. `[1,2,3].uniq! #=> nil`

Comment: Given that the return value of `myarray.uniq!` is not used, it does not matter what it returns.  Either duplicate ids have been discarded or `myarray` is the same as before the call.